# AOt Compilation no such file or directory

Tags: angular, node-modules, angular2-aot

I am trying to do --aot compilation of my angular 4 project .

my tsconfig.json file is

`{
   "compileOnSave": false,
   "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": false,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": [
         "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "lib": [
         "es2017",
         "dom"
      ]
   }
}`

command i am using is `ng build --aot`

I am using a plugin named `bp-datepicker` which is giving error on `aot` compilation although it works fine on `JIT` compilation .

`no such file or directory, open 'pathroproject\project\node_modules\bp-datepicker\bp-datepicker.component.html'`

angular-cli version:
"@angular/cli": "1.3.1",

angular core version:
"@angular/core": "^4.2.4",

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `--base-href`

complete commant:

```
ng build --base-href /Name_of_Project/ --prod --aot
```

Comment: doesn't work , can you please try on your side once